# How do you print 2 functions next to each other?

Tags: python

```
import webbrowser
import random

idr = random.randint(10000, 9999999)
link = 'view&id='

webbrowser.open(link,idr)
```

with this code it generates the id and puts it at the end of the link as an id for an image however i have found that it wont work as it puts a space between the links = and the id

Comment: This is what [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) are for.

Comment: what happens if you try `+`.  `webbrowser.open(link+str(idr))`. This should solve it

Comment: [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open) - `webbrowser.open` does not concatenate mutliple string arguments into a URL.